# Validate method is ignored when decorating validation attribute for hidden property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a C# MVC view model called PersonViewModel that inherits the **IValidatableObject**. There is a property named ClickCount that is integer type. That property is **hidden** on an MVC view, but it is used to count user clicking on some another visible view element (html element). The requirement for that hidden property is a **positive** integer. That means user must clicks the other html element at least 1. If user does not click that other html element, then when he/she submits the form to the server via MVC controller POST action method named Save(), the MVC validation error should be brought back to the view page.

*The Validation method is used for validating **other properties** of my MVC model as well and those validation tasks were ignored because the Validation method was ignored as a whole.*

To force the validation, in my view model PersonViewModel, I had decorated the **hidden** property ClickCount as:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The Bell button must be clicked at least 1")]
public int ClickCount { get; set; }
```

That decorating for that hidden property was wrong because it caused the overriden Validation() method of my MVC model PersonViewModel **is ignored or not never hit**, the debugged ModelState.IsValid was always **true** although user does not hit the other html element. So, I had to remove the validation attribute for that hidden property. Instead, I moved the validation logic inside the overridden Validation method.

The the overridden Validation method of my view model also contains validation logic for other model properties, too.

**My question**: why did the validation attribute for hidden property on the MVC view markup page cause the Validation method to be ignored?

The following was my MVC model that has wrong validation attribute for the hidden property ClickCount:

```
public class PersonViewModel: IValidatableObject
    {
       [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The Bell button must be clicked at least 1")]
    public int ClickCount { get; set; }

        }

        #region validation

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
           …. // logic to validate properties
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The MVC cshtml view with the property ClickCount which is hidden:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClickCount, null)
```

My controller POST action method which was always hit with ModelState.IsValid which alwasy true because the overriden Validation() method was ignored.

```
public ActionResult Save(PersonViewModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       ....
   }
}
```

I appreciate your explanation, ideas.

Comment: Sorry ! What you mean the "That decorating for that hidden property was wrong" ? It should work. What specific problem are you having with that ?

Comment: The validation on `ClickCount` should work for hidden element as well.

Comment: @Shyju Thank you for your reply. Yes the validation for the hidden property was validated.  However, the problem as I said in the topic of this post was the overridden Validation method of my MVC model was ignored. All the logic codes inside that method were not executed because the Validation method was ignored.  The Validation method is used for validating OTHER  properties of my MVC model as well.